# Angular 8 Refresh component on array updated on service

Tags: angular, angular8

updating service arrays value from parent component and on change that array want to update child components value and view .
both components view are visible same time.
OverviewComponent is parent Component , settting searched value from here to 
CommonModuleService and then calling child component want to use that searched array in SearchComponent(childComponent)

```
  export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {  //ParentComponent     
  filteredProjects: any = [];
  Projects: any = [];
  constructor(private router: Router, private commonModuleService: CommonModuleService,
              private projectService: ProjectService) {
  };
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredProjects = this.commonModuleService.filteredProjects;
  }
  searchOperation() {
    this.projectService.find(false).subscribe((response: ProjectModel[]) => {
      if (response) {
        this.projects = response;
        //HERE SEARCH code then matching records get pushing into newProjects
        this.commonModuleService.filteredProjects = this.newProjects;
        this.router.navigate(['overview/search']);
      }
    });
  }
}
export class CommonModuleService {
  public filteredProjects: ProjectModel[];
  constructor() {
  }
  public setFilteredProjects(filteredProjects) {
    this.filteredProjects = filteredProjects;
  }
  public getFilteredProjects() {
    return this.filteredProjects;
  }
}
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  public filteredProjects: ProjectModel[];
  constructor(private  internalService: InternalService,
              private projectService: ProjectService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private commonModuleService: CommonModuleService) {
    this.filteredProjects = commonModuleService.filteredProjects;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredProjects = this.commonModuleService.filteredProjects;
  }
}
//search.component.html   on change value this  view need to be updated 
<li class = 'project-search-list-item' * ngFor = 'let project of filteredProjects' >
  {{project.name}}
  </li>;
```

Comment: Can you post some code? That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: please check now code added for better understanding

Comment: Are you using your service as a singleton? Can you tell me if you added your service to any module array of providers and if your service has `providedIn` property?

Comment: yes @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) is defined on CommonModuleService,

Comment: The problem is when i pass searchedItems array from OverviewComponent(parent) it also applies on service but it works only once when i redirect on search from other page , if  i am already on search page it will not update data. if i redirect to another page andcomes back to search page then getting latest data.

Comment: solved like this   
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/overview', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/overview/search']);
          });